# Overload resolution with TryParse

Tags: f#

We have a function converting things like `Int32.TryParse` from using a byref to using an Option for the return value.

```
let inline ToOptionFunc refFunction x =
    match refFunction x with
    | true, value  -> Some value
    | false, _     -> None
```

Stuff like this stopped compiling in .NET Core with the new overloads to TryParse:

```
let Int32TryParse (x:string) =
     ToOptionFunc Int32.TryParse x // A unique overload for method 'TryParse' could not be determined (...)
```

I tried many things and accidentally got it to work by writing it like this instead:

```
let Int32TryParse (x:string) =
     x |> ToOptionFunc Int32.TryParse
```

I just don't understand why this compiles and the former does not.

Comment: Why do you convert `Int32.TryParse` at all? It can already be used directly like in your first code block.

Comment: So it plays better with F# code. e.g. `tryParse >> Option.map`

Comment: Ah, sorry, I missed that part.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In .NET Core, the `Int32.TryParse` function has some extra overloads - it can parse either `string` or `ReadOnlySpan<char>`. The original code stopped working, because the compiler did not know which overload you wanted to use.

- In the version without pipe, the compiler needs to type-check `ToOptionFunc Int32.TryParse x`. It proceeds from left to right and when it gets to `Int32.TryParse`, it does not yet know about `x` (which has a type annotation constraining that to `string`) and without knowing about `x`, it cannot know which `TryParse` you need.
- In the version with pipe, the compiler needs to type-check `x |> ToOptionFunc Int32.TryParse`. It proceeds from left to right and knows that `x` is `string`, so it then infers that the function passed to `ToOptionFunc` must also be taking `string` - and when it checks `Int32.TryParse`, it can already uniquely determine the overload.

The summary is, pipe has very nice properties for guiding type-checking!